# How to add AJAX to a page after WordPress get_header()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a page that is not part of WordPress, except that I am calling in get_header() and get_footer() from the WordPress library in order to wrap it in the same theme as the other pages.

However, after get_header() is called, if I try to call any sort of AJAX, it just gets ignored. Do these blocks need to be added within the header tags only, or is there some other conflict with WordPress? Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."wp-config.php" );
global $current_user;
get_currentuesrinfo();
get_header();
global $wpdb;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function () {
    $('#AdminForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax/save.php',
            data: $('#AdminForm').serialize();
            success: function () {
                alert('form was saved');
                }
            });
        });
    });
//-->
</script>

<form name="AdminForm" id="AdminForm">
<input type="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

I found the following error in the Chrome developer tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Is there a proper way to do this that won't conflict with WordPress?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Yes I did. I've been trying every "alternative" approach I can find to call this.. jQuery, $(document).ready, function($), and $(function ()) so far...

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Wordpress using jQuery in [no-conflict mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). Try setting it up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#AdminForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax/save.php',
            data: $('#AdminForm').serialize();
            success: function() {
                alert('form was saved');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now you can use the standard `$` for all of your functions within the document ready function.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. It looks like it gets rid of the "$ is not a function" error in Developer Tools, but it still doesn't work. I expect that when the button is pushed, it should NOT submit the form, but instead open an alert box which says "form was saved" ... instead, it just submits the form.